# How to build a window on the top of all others window on Android

Tags: android, window, android-windowmanager

I want to build a view on the top of every window.

I found this code:

```
bt = new Button(getApplicationContext());
LayoutParams param = new LayoutParams();
param.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
param.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
param.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT;
param.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
param.width = 40;
param.height = 40;
wmgr = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wmgr.addView(bt, param);
```

and in `manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

The view is built but when I press the home button, I can't see anything except the status bar.

What's wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
wmgr = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

To

```
wmgr = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

Comment: is it possible to add such a view to the notification bar area ?
what about the bottom buttons-toolbar , like on android 3 and android 4 ?

i wish to add functionality that can be shown there as well . of course i should make the position customized...